# Learning Arduino and Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to learn how to send messages from the Raspberry Pi 4 to the Arduino Mega 2650 device via USB cable for use in a Jukebox project.  I'm starting by doing some tutorials and I'm stumped as to a certain behavior.  I hope someone can help me.

Here is the code on the Arduino Mega device:

```
#define LED_2_PIN 2
#define LED_3_PIN 3
#define LED_4_PIN 4

void powerOffAllLEDs() {
  digitalWrite(LED_2_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_3_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_4_PIN, LOW);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_2_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_3_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_4_PIN, OUTPUT);

  powerOffAllLEDs();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    
    int ledNumber = Serial.read() - '0';
    powerOffAllLEDs();
    switch (ledNumber) {
      case 2:
        digitalWrite(LED_2_PIN, HIGH);
        break;
      case 3:
        digitalWrite(LED_3_PIN, HIGH);
        break;
      case 4:
        digitalWrite(LED_4_PIN, HIGH);
        break;
      default: 
        // wrong pin number, do nothing
        // all LEDs will be powered off
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

If I run this code on the Raspberry Pi, I see one of the LED's flash quickly on and off.

```
import time, serial

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.flush()
while True:
    ser.write(b"4\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

If I run this code on the Raspberry Pi, I don't see any LED's light-up.

```
import time, serial

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.flush()
ser.write(b"4\n")
time.sleep(1)
```

If I comment out the "powerOffAllLEDs()" just before the switch statement on the Arduino, then the light stays on with the first Raspberry Pi code.  It still does nothing with the second.

Its almost like the "Serial.available()" is picking up stuff from the Raspberry Pi even though it shouldn't be sending anything.

This is obviously just a tutorial I'm trying to understand...ultimately I need to be able to send a two character (1 letter and 1 number - ie. "A1") code and have the LED stay on until I send another code.

Comment: the Arduino resets on new USB connection and spends some time in bootloader waiting for upload

Comment: So, if I want the Arduino to react to something from the Raspberry Pi, I need to put it in a loop?  Then, have some acknowlegement back from the Arduino stating it received the message so the Raspberry Pi can continue with it's code?  I can't have the Raspberry Pi in a perm loop just to make a light come on.

Comment: don't connect again every time you want to send something.

Comment: Each of the Rasperry Pi code is only establishing the serial connection once.  The only difference is that is one of them I have to do a loop to continue sending the string (4 in this case) while the second Raspberry Pi code is only sending once.

Comment: that is all you want to do? add a pause after connection

Comment: That was it!!!  That never occurred to me.  Thank you!!